# IntelliSense can find C++ header files, compiler can not (VSCODE)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying to include the SOCI library in my C++ library. The compilation fails with:

```
fatal error: soci/soci.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "soci/soci.h"
```

I have downloaded and built the library in the path:

```
/users/niko/.env/libraries
```

My c_cpp_properties.json looks like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "users/niko/.env/libraries/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/opt/devtoolset//gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-Wall",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wconversion",
                "-Wpedantic",
                "-I /users/niko/.env/libraries/include/**"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And correspondingly, the tasks.json looks like:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp build active file",
            "command": "/opt/devtoolset//cpp",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I",
                 "users/niko/.env/libraries/include/*",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /opt/devtoolset//cpp"
        }
    ]
}
```

IntelliSense correctly finds it from this path, but the compilation fails. I have tried various things on SO, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Maybe a bit pedantic, but are you sure it's not because you forgot a `/` in the beginning in this line: `"users/niko/.env/libraries/include/*"`?

Comment: Tried adding -- I still get the compilation error.